# Delete method in ROR route error when using remote true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to delete post with the `remote: true` command in rails. Everything is working fine when i'm not using ajax. But when i use the remote true command i get an routing error.

view:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.title %>
  <%= link_to 'delete', post_path(post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end

def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.destroy
  redirect_to :back
end
```

routes:

```
resources :posts
```

This is the error i get in the log.

```
Started DELETE "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-11 12:46:33 +0200
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/posts"):
```

Thanks in advance.

Update. I get this when i write `rake routes`.

```
DELETE     /posts/:id(.:format)                   posts#destroy
```

Comment: try this `<%= link_to 'delete', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true %>`

Comment: The backend is reporting that there's no method delete route, so the frontend is sending the correct method, but the issue is in the routing, but the routing seems fine, try running `rake routes` and make sure you have the correct route in the routes

Comment: It do work anusha. Thanks! But for some reason it seems like it is making two delete request to different routes. If i look in the log i get this first "Started DELETE "/posts/198" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-11 14:28:03 +0200" and right after i get this "Started DELETE "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-11 14:28:03 +0200" which i get a routing error on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to working.

Change:

```
def destroy
 @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
 @posts.destroy
 redirect_to :back
end
```

To this:

```
def destroy
 @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
 @posts.destroy
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
  format.js { head :no_content }
 end
end
```

and:

```
<%= link_to 'delete', post_path(post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true %>
```

to:

```
<%= link_to 'delete', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone is having any problems with this, I managed to solve it by adding `:data => { :type => :json }` to the link.

For example:

```
<%= link_to "Delete this post", @post, :method => :delete, :remote => true, :data => { :type => :json } %>
```

I imagine UJS is expecting HTML, however JSON is returned so it fails and posts again (I noticed two requests).

Hope this helps!